# Monotouch: Building a "console"?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, uiweb

I'm building a client/server app. The server sends me lots of information, that I need to display on the iPhone in a "console". I need to display several of columns (time, user, message).

What is the best approach for this?

I thought about creating a UIWebView and create a table .. but will I be able to add rows as information comes from the server? Can I hook into a table in the UIWebView and add a new row now and then?

Should I build it using a UITableView?

What would you do?

Thanks!!!

Mojo

Answer (score 0):

I would have used a `UITableViewController` and create a `TableDataSource` which would read the rows from the server.
You can either format the row or use a custom control for it (I usually use custom row control).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how sophisticated your UI needs to be but if the basic look is enough, why not simply use a `UITextView` and format it using tabs?
You can then keep on appending text as you receive it.
To prevent the user from messing around with it, just set `UserInteractionEnabled` to `false`.